# Excel calculate increase in value every 200ms

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet, vba

I have this worksheet which gets data from API and its refreshes itself every 200 milliseconds. I want to calculate the change in value which is constantly increasing every 200 ms. For example Cell B2 has a value of 4 after 200 ms its changes to 7 then to 16 then to 26 etc, it just keeps adding value into it. All I want is to subtract the old value from the latest value to get the change for example 7-4=3 or 16-7=9 or 26-16=10.

I have added an image for clarification. This shows how I'm getting a data from software. [image: worksheet]

And one more image:

[image: worksheet]

Comment: How does the worksheet get data from API? What API is used? Do you have any code?

Comment: Its a Forex software with excel integration it doesnt require any code all you have to do is just make new excel file on desktop and from software point that excel file and all data just starts showing on excel file like its in the software. And the cell i mention has a value of total traded volume on that object which keep increasing every 200ms

Comment: Can't open an image by the link you provided (it just redirected to http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2uny5w2&s=9#.WBu4ji197bg). What do you intend to do with computed difference? Do you want to store this value somewhere each 200 ms, or just to display on another sheet?

Comment: Sorry mate. but it works fine here.

Comment: No i dont want to store this value all i want is subtract the value which was 200ms before with the latest value (after 200ms). for example, at 03:14:25:200 (H:M:S:MS) the value was $2568 and at 03:14:25:400 (H:M:S:MS) the value increased to $2601. Now i want to subtract the old vlaue from the latest value which will give me the change. $2601-$2568= $33. This is what i want. Please help me thanks.

Comment: I can see the image now ... i hope its visible for you too. in this image C column is auto-update and i want change in values in D.

Comment: I want one more thing to update. If day cell changes its value all values set to zero or reset in calculation table.. because i left it to record data and when date changes values staring to giving me negative answers because next day values were smaller than yesterdays values. and whole sheet went in negative.

Comment: Thats Date cell not day cell. typo error

Comment: Please edit your question to add new details: the code you are running (for proper formatting see help), screenshot of the worksheet, and what is current and expected output. Comments are not for extended discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest VBA solution, based on worksheet change event handling. Open **VBA Project** and put the below code into the target worksheet in **Microsoft Excel Objects** section:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime via Menu - Tools - References

    Const Scope = "C2:C5" ' monitoring area
    Const DX = 1 ' horizontal result offset
    Const DY = 0 ' vertical result offset
    Const Buf = 0 ' FIFO buffer size

    Static oData(0 To Buf) As New Dictionary
    Static oIndex As New Dictionary
    Dim rCells As Range
    Dim oCell
    Dim i As Long

    Set rCells = Application.Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range(Scope))
    If Not rCells Is Nothing Then
        For Each oCell In rCells
            With oCell
                i = oIndex(.Address)
                .Offset(DY, DX).Value = .Value - oData(i)(.Address)
                oData(i)(.Address) = .Value
                i = i + 1
                If i > Buf Then i = 0
                oIndex(.Address) = i
            End With
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

I added some comments for constants. Set the range which change to be monitored in `Scope`, the offsets where the resulting delta will be output in `DX` and `DY`, and as a bonus that algorithm supports computing delta not only between last and previous numbers, but also between any number of frames for each target cell via buffer organized as array of dictionaries, so set the size of the buffer in `Buf`, if you do not want to use the buffer then just leave `0` size, e. g. the value of `3` will compute delta between the last value and the one  delayed by 800 ms for your case.

**UPDATE**

There is slightly simplified version of the code as requested in comment, put the below code into the target worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const Scope = "C2:C5" ' monitoring area

    Static oData As New Dictionary
    Dim rCells As Range
    Dim oCell
    Dim dDelta

    Set rCells = Application.Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range(Scope))
    If Not rCells Is Nothing Then
        For Each oCell In rCells
            With oCell
                dDelta = .Value - oData(.Address)
                If dDelta <> 0 Then
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = dDelta
                    oData(.Address) = .Value
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: how do i setup DX and DY? and the second code why cant i use that code in the same worksheet?

Comment: @Yasir I removed excessive VBS for testing, and changed buffer size to 0. All constants now already set up correctly and ready to use. Have you placed the code in the worksheet? Do any values appear in column `D` after column `C` changed?

Comment: i am getting an error "compile error user-defined type not defined" and then it highlight this line "oData(0 To Buf) As New Dictionary"

Comment: i have also added references vba project .. but still not working

Comment: i have added this new library microsoft word 15.0 object libraray now the error is complie error "invalid use of new keyword"

Comment: @Yasir read the code in my answer carefully, there is the comment `add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

Comment: Sorry again. i have one more question why the value doesn't stay until it changes? what is happening right now is that it shows me a value which is impossible to see because it turns it into zero straight away. Isnt there anyway where it stays until it changes rather than going back to zero.

Comment: @Yasir that means the Forex software updates the worksheet more often, e. g. putting the new value at the first time it changes the worksheet, and other 9 times just repeating the same value. Try to increase `Buf` constant value experimentally, one by one, until the result will not turn into zero immediately.

Comment: i tried that but didn't work. can i record every cell indiviually?? like if put only one cell in range. i tried to put that but didn't work. just wondering how do i put one cell instead of range.

Comment: ok i got the problem at this line ".Offset(DY, DX).Value = .Value - oData(i)(.Address)" its actually subtracting the new value to old if i am not wrong. In my case if the value didnt change then its subtracting it from the same value and the answer is zero. is there is any way if the old is equal to new value then do not subtract? instead show me an old value?

Comment: @Yasir try the code within Update section of the answer

Comment: i change this and this work fine "If .Value > oData(i)(.Address) Then .Offset(DY, DX).Value = .Value - oData(i)(.Address)" you i will give a try to your looks more stable. Anyways Thank you so much for your help. I wish i could give you a hug hahaha. Need more people like you. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

First, enable Iterative Calculations in Excel by going to File -> Options -> Formulas and then checking the box next to "Enable iterative calculation".

You need to define the following cells:

```
cell B1     0 (set to 1 to reset)
cell B2     =IF($B$1 = 1,, $B$2 + 1)
```

Use the following formula and fill down from B9 for as many changes as you would like to see (This formula assumes you have maximum iterations set to 100):

`cell B9     =IF($B$1 = 1,"", IF($B$2 / 100 = $A9, $B$5, B9))`

I will try to show an example here. If your cell that automatically updates is B5, then the changes will be tracked in B9 and below as the cell is refreshed. It may not be exactly what you are looking for, but I think it is close.

```
     A      B
1    reset  0
2    count  500
3       
4       
5    price  9
6       
7       
8    ID     price
9    1      11
10   2      12
11   3      13
12   4      12
13   5      9
```

Comment: I have added a image in my question to clarify my question ... this show how i am getting a data from software. http://i64.tinypic.com/2uny5w2.png

Comment: Are you getting an error or just not getting the desired output? It will need to be modified in order to update in a single cell.